# WindowsError: priveledged instruction when saving a FreeImagePy Image in script, works in IDLE

Tags: python, exception, windowserror

I'm working on a program to do some image wrangling in Python for work.  I'm using FreeImagePy because PIL doesn't support multi-page TIFFs.  Whenever I try to save a file with it from my program I get this error message (or something similar depending on which way I try to save):

```
Error returned.  TIFF FreeImage_Save: failed to open file C:/OCRtmp/ocr page0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python25\Projects\OCRPageUnzipper\PageUnzipper.py", line 102, in <mod
ule> OCRBox.convertToPages("C:/OCRtmp/ocr page",FIPY.FIF_TIFF)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\FreeImagePy\FreeImagePy\FreeImagePy.py", l
ine 2080, in convertToPages self.Save(FIF, dib, fileNameOut, flags)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\FreeImagePy\FreeImagePy\FreeImagePy.py", l
ine 187, in Save return self.__lib.Save(typ, bitmap, fileName, flags)
WindowsError: exception: priviledged instruction
```

When I try and do the same things from IDLE, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a permission issues, make sure you don't have the file open in another application, and that you have write permissions to the file location your trying to write to.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I thought too, but I figured it out a couple hours ago.  Apparently if the directory/file I'm trying to write to doesn't exist, FreeImagePy isn't smart enough to create it (most of the time.  Creating a new multipage image seems to work fine) but i guess running it within IDLE, IDLE figures it out and takes care of it or something.  I managed to work around it by using os.mkdir to explicitly make sure things that I need exist.